# Remove facets from breadcrumb

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs, search

I'm using FacetAPI-SearchAPI and I notice that, on every view based on search api in the breadcrumb there is the "all items" link and, when I add a facet to the search, the facet value is added to the breadcrumb.

Is there a way to remove "all items" and other facets elements from the breadcrumb?

Answer (score 4):

In `/sites/all/modules/facetapi/plugins/facetapi/url_processor_standard.inc` there's a function `setBreadcrumb()` (around line 61).

Simply comment it out or put a `return;` on line 62.

A better way is to create your URL Processor which implements `FacetapiUrlProcessor::setBreadcrumb()`

Answer (score 2):

**This is something I used to reset the breadcrumb**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_facetapi_searcher_info()
 */
function yourmodule_facetapi_searcher_info_alter(array &$searcher_info) {
  foreach ($searcher_info as $key => $value) {
    if($value['url processor'] == 'standard'){
      $searcher_info[$key]['url processor'] = 'yourprocessor';
    }
  }
}


function yourmodule_facetapi_url_processors() {
  return array(
    'yourprocessor' => array(
      'handler' => array(
        'label' => t('Your module URL processor'),
        'class' => 'FacetApiYourClass',
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class FacetApiYourClass extends FacetapiUrlProcessorStandard {
  public function setBreadcrumb() {
    // Keep default behavior.
  }
}
```